# How can I guarantee row consistency with a Master-Master database replication?

Tags: mysql, database-design, replication, database-replication

I have a process that makes a call to a 3rd party system to perform some action.  My users can schedule these calls in my web application, which inserts a row in my database.  A scheduled process will check my database for any outstanding requests every hour and attempt to make the calls to the 3rd party service.  Users can also opt to manually make calls they have scheduled in the web application.

I want to avoid a situation where the scheduled process and a user attempt to make the call at the same time.  To add this safety I introduced different row statuses: "waiting" for new rows, "trying" for rows being attempted, and then "complete" for completed ones and "error" for ones that failed.

The first step in attempting the 3rd party call is to update the status from "waiting" to "trying" using a SQL statement like this:

```
UPDATE remote_calls SET status = "trying" WHERE status = "waiting" AND id = ?;
```

If rows affected = 0, exit.  If rows affected = 1, try to make the call.  Thus if the user and the scheduled process attempt to make the same call concurrently only one will succeed and the other one will exit.

This works fine on my test box but I found out that it will be deployed in a master-master replication environment.  Do I have a problem?  I worry that if user's attempt and scheduled process attempt update different masters, both of the updates will succeed.  Is this a legitimate worry?  If so, is there any way I can guarantee that only one of these will succeed?